# Can JBehave or Surefire report individual tests from a JUnitStories test suite?

Tags: junit, maven-surefire-plugin, jbehave

I use the Surefire Maven plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Dhttp.proxyHost=${http.proxyHost}
      -Dhttp.proxyPort=${http.proxyPort}</argLine>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

to run multiple JBehave tests with JUnitStories

```
public class SystemTest extends JUnitStories {
  protecetd List<String> storyPaths() {
    // returns a list of multiple JBehave files
  }
}
```

and get a single-line report that summarizes the whole test suite:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: <path>.SystemTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.803 sec - 
in <path>.SystemTest
```

Can I configure JUnitStories or Surefire such that I get one line for each file given by storyPaths()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around with the configuration for a while, I gave up and wrote a custom JBehave reporter that writes multiple JUnit result files, one for each story file.